# Read variable length messages over SPI using Low Level (LL) api on STM32 MCU

Tags: interrupt, stm32, spi, variable-length

My system is composed by an STM32NUCLEO board and a slave device connected over SPI. The slave device sends commands with a variable length: possible lengths are 4, 8, 10, 14 bits.

I'm trying to detect these messages on my nucleo board using the LL APIs and interrupts.

The solution I'm currently working on is based on setting the SPI with a data-width of 4 bits (**SPI_InitStruct.DataWidth = LL_SPI_DATAWIDTH_4BIT**) and then counting the number of words (1 word = 4 bits) that I receive. In this way, if I receive 1 word then it means that I have received a 4 bit command, 2 word --> 8 bit command. If I receive 3 words, it should mean that I have received a 10bit command (2 bits should be discarded), and so on.

Unfortunately, I have noticed that the LL APIs provides functions only for reading 8 bits or 16 bits at a time and currently I'm having issue in receiving a 4 bit command, since the function **LL_SPI_ReceiveData8** expects to receive 8 bits.

Here is my implementation for the IRQ handler and for the callback:

**IRQ Handler:**

```
void SPI1_IRQHandler(void)
{
  /* Check RXNE flag value in ISR register */
  if(LL_SPI_IsActiveFlag_RXNE(SPI1))
  {
    /* Call function Slave Reception Callback */
    SPI1_Rx_Callback();
  }
  /* Check STOP flag value in ISR register */
  else if(LL_SPI_IsActiveFlag_OVR(SPI1))
  {
    /* Call Error function */
    SPI1_TransferError_Callback();
  }
}
```

**Callback**

```
void SPI1_Rx_Callback(void)
{
  /* Read character in Data register.
  RXNE flag is cleared by reading data in DR register */
  aRxBuffer[ubReceiveIndex++] = LL_SPI_ReceiveData8(SPI1);
}
```

As said before in my opinion, the problem seems that I'm using the **LL_SPI_ReceiveData8** function to read since I could not find something like **LL_SPI_ReceiveData4**.

Do you have some suggestions?

Furthermore, is it possible to set the SPI to use 2 bit datawidth instead of 4? Something like **SPI_InitStruct.DataWidth = LL_SPI_DATAWIDTH_2BIT**: in this way it should be easier to detect the commands since 4, 8, 10 and 14 are multiples of 2.

Thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

With the new information about the used controller:

It supports SPI data transfer length between 4 and 16 bit. So your first try seems not so bad.

Your "problem" is that there is no 4 bit read function. This is caused by the receive data register that will always contain 16 bit but there are only 4 bit valid data in your case. the other bits are '0'.

Your callback function

```
aRxBuffer[ubReceiveIndex++] = LL_SPI_ReceiveData8(SPI1);
```

will write values from 0..15 to the aRxBuffer and you don't need a
**LL_SPI_ReceiveData4()** to get your answer :-)

So also the Reference manual for the STM32L4 series [Reference Manual](http://www.st.com/content/ccc/resource/technical/document/reference_manual/group0/b0/ac/3e/8f/6d/21/47/af/DM00151940/files/DM00151940.pdf/jcr:content/translations/en.DM00151940.pdf) at page 1333f.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. I don't know about the F4 family, but LL_SPI_DATAWIDTH_4BIT is definitely supported for the L4 family, the one that I'm using. I have generated the project using CubeMX version 4.25.1. My problem is that I don't see a corresponding function for reading just 4 bit. But, apparently, as PeterJ_01 says since the minimum is 8 bits, I guess I will need to go with that.

Comment: You cant read 4 bits. Even if the SPI hardware does it, you read the 8 bits data from the data register.

Comment: I've just had a look ad the reference manual for the STM32L4 chip. And it supports SPI transfer length  from 4 to 16 bit.

Answer (score 0):

The minimal addresable chunk of data is byte. So even if you receive the 4 bits the read value is 8 bits.

BTW wht is this secret slave device which have varing word length?

Comment: Thank you both for your answer. The slave device is composed by a simulator that communicates using the SpaceWire protocol and an HW interface for converting Data Strobe to SPI.

Comment: The controller is a nucleo board based on STM32L432KCU mcu.

Comment: I am asking about the slave device

Comment: SpaceWire Brick Mk3

Comment: It does not have the SPI interface - at least as see on their website

Comment: Yes, but my setup includes an HW interface to convert Data Strobe to SPI and vice-versa. Please refer to my previous message.

Comment: Where is the datasheet of that device?

Comment: The HW interface is a custom made board and I don't have a datasheet available. Sorry.